# How to order by self.created_at and children.created_at in find conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing with Rails 2.2.2 and ruby 1.8.6.

I want to order `Topic` model which has many comments by the latest `comments.created_at` or `self.created_at` if there is no comment.

```
＃<Topic id: 1, :created_at: "2012-03-12-10:00:00">
＃<Topic id: 2, :created_at: "2012-03-13-09:00:00">
   =>＃<Comment topic_id: 2, :created_at: "2012-03-15-16:00:00">
＃<Topic id: 3, :created_at: "2012-03-14-14:00:00">
   =>＃<Comment topic_id: 3, :created_at: "2012-03-14-16:00:00">

# Order should be => Topic id 2,3,1
```

I've wrote conditions that pass two order condition, but that order by first condition.

```
Topic.find(:all, :order=>"topics.created_at desc, comments.created_at desc",    :include=>"comments")

# Order is => Topic id 3,2,1
```

I know that `sort_by` is easy to order, but I want to order by order parameter in find method because I use paginating_find plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, you can order them like this:

```
:order => "IFNULL(comments.created_at, topics.created_at) DESC"
```

Other DBMSs should have similar functions.

Comment: Thank you so much.
This is what I want!